# Allow users to add and georeference photos in ArcGIS Online or Portal

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, photos, geotag

Ideally a user could drag and drop a photo and then click on the map to georeference and add a photo to an online database for future reference.   Is this possible with existing tools in ArcGIS Online or Portal?

Answer (score 1):

We just released Media Layers in Map Viewer which allow you do some lightweight georef. Currently that have to be saved in the map but saving them off as items is planned on the ML roadmap.
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/announcing-media-layers/